# Smoothing Tangents using existing normals. OpenGL Lighting

Tags: opengl, math, graphics

I have a bunch of meshes that make up a Terrain. Not one BIG mesh. It's from a game and I'm making a tool for players to plan battles.

All the meshes contain are the Vertices and averaged normals. No tangents.

I can create the tangents and Bi-Tangents easy enough BUT, it looks bad. They need to be smoothed out or averaged together, as usual. I would need to create one big mesh from the small ones to do smoothing. Seems like a lot of work for nothing.

My question is, because I already have the normals in the smoothed/averaged state, is there any way to use them to correct the tangent?

I was creating the TBN matrix in the shader using [This Method](http://www.geeks3d.com/20130122/normal-mapping-without-precomputed-tangent-space-vectors). It works but, The over head is costly as I'm drawing hundreds of thousands of 4 layer, blended by mix texture, texels.

**Update**

OK... one can NOT as far as I can tell use a normal for this..
I spend all day yesterday writing code to create on giant mesh and then turning it back in to its section meshes.
For Nico Shhertler :

```
for(int i = 0; i < getVerts().length; i += 3) {
     Vector3f v0 = getVerts()[i].getVectorXYZ();
     Vector3f v1 = getVerts()[i + 1].getVectorXYZ();
     Vector3f v2 = getVerts()[i + 2].getVectorXYZ();

     Vector2f uv0 = getVerts()[i].getVectorUV();
     Vector2f uv1 = getVerts()[i + 1].getVectorUV();
     Vector2f uv2 = getVerts()[i + 2].getVectorUV();

     Vector3f n = getVerts()[i].getVectorNXYZ();

     Vector3f deltaPos1 = new Vector3f();
     Vector3f.sub(v1, v0, deltaPos1);
     Vector3f deltaPos2 = new Vector3f();
     Vector3f.sub(v2, v0, deltaPos2);

     float deltaUv1 = uv1.getY() - uv0.getY();
     float deltaUv2 = uv2.getY() - uv0.getY();

     // Tangent
     float tx = (deltaPos1.getX() * deltaUv2) - (deltaPos2.getX() * deltaUv1);
     float ty = (deltaPos1.getY() * deltaUv2) - (deltaPos2.getY() * deltaUv1);
     float tz = (deltaPos1.getZ() * deltaUv2) - (deltaPos2.getZ() * deltaUv1);
     Vector3f t = new Vector3f(tx, ty, tz);

     // Bitangent
     Vector3f b = new Vector3f();
     Vector3f.cross(n, t, b);

     // Final tangent
     Vector3f smoothTangent = new Vector3f();
     Vector3f.cross(b, n, smoothTangent);
     smoothTangent.normalise();

                   // These are where I store all the vertex data, so it's one tangent per vertex.
     getVerts()[i].setTXYZ(smoothTangent);
     getVerts()[i + 1].setTXYZ(smoothTangent);
     getVerts()[i + 2].setTXYZ(smoothTangent);
  }
```

Comment: And can you show this *easy-enough* method you use to calculate tangents?

Comment: Well.. Its a lot a code... that wont fit in an comment but works the same as most methods. See if this helps you [link]http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=33259.0
Its basically what I'm doing.

Comment: You can edit your question to add more information (which you should do for the code). It seems as if you are just overwriting any tangent that may already be there for a vertex instead of averaging over all incident faces. What you can do additionally is to track the corresponding vertices in neighboring patches and factor that into the averaging as you would normally do.

Comment: The vertices contain nothing but location..The normals are stored in a PNG image, averaged and is compressed to contain X and Z only. The PNG already has the normals in the smoothed state. I'm working with terrain blocks from a game and was looking for an easy solution..however, while thinking about this problem, I ended up rebuilding the data and averaging the TBNs. I posted an answer and as far as I can tell, it works if all you have are normals in a averaged state.  Its called the orthogonal correction or Gram-Schmidt process.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there is a way to use the normal to align the tangent and the bitangent with the average/smoothed normal.

These 2 lines force the Tangent and BiTangent to 90 degrees with the normal.
The "Gram-Schmidt process"

```
t = normalize(t-dot(n,t)*n);
b = normalize(b-dot(n,b)*n);
```